# Drupal Displaying Images in block

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7

I have problem with displaying img in my block.

I created block with images:

[image]

Mode "Full Html" :

```
<p><img alt="" src="/sites/default/documents/f_logo_1.jpg">
<img alt="" src="/sites/default/documents/f_logo_2.jpg">
<img alt="" src="/sites/default/documents/f_logo_3.jpg" style="height:48px; width:104px">
<img alt="" src="/sites/default/documents/f_logo_4.png" style="height:44px; width:211px"></p>
```

But after save, i see only title and no one tag img. Also i tried add text like "lorem..." and its work with all other tag like strong, p, em.

Thank you for attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution :) It was problem with Text Formats.

Solutions is : Configuration -> Content writing ->Text Formats and HTML tags authorized

```
<a> <em> <strong> <cite> <blockquote> <code> <ul> <ol> <li> <dl> <dt> <dd><img>
```

Comment: It's great =) Strange that <img> wasn't in this list. It's by default here for Full HTML. Feel free to mark your or mine answer is "correct" to help other guys with same issue

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like Text Filtering issue, but if you have Full HTML mode - all must be good. Ok, try this:

1. Go to modules page and enable PHP filter module (core module)
2. Save your block with PHP code mode
3. It MUST work =)

Answer (score -1):

try to place image in a div or p like

```
<div>

 <div><img src="" /></div>
 <div><img src="" /></div>
 <div><img src="" /></div>
 <div><img src="" /></div>

</div>
```

Comment: i tried to add p, em and strong, and I got : <p><em><strong>   </strong></em></p>